# Relationship between FFT sampling rate, Bandwidth, and Resolution

Tags: fft, resolution

I´m trying to write a code for omitting one sideband of FFT and shift the other on to the center, 
I know the sampling rate (2 GHz) and the number of samples is (10000) the sidebands located in (-55,-355) and (55,355)
I want to know the frequency resolution of each spectral line 
this is the code I´ve written...

```
   void compfft (double *source, double *destination, int length)

         {
double *realPart = malloc(length*sizeof(double));
double *ImgPart = malloc(length*sizeof(double));
       int index,i,j; 
for (index= 0;index< length; index++)
      {
   realPart[index] = source[index];   //data to a local array
       }
memset(ImgPart, 0, sizeof(ImgPart));
FFT(realPart, ImgPart, length);     //Take fft

         //shifting the destination array 
         for(i=0; i<(length/4) ; i++){
 *destination[i]=* realPart[i+749];
            }

        //filling the destination array with source array values from 55 Hz to 355 Hz 
        for(j=99; j<(length/5); j++){
 destination[j] = realPart[j+750];
            }

         free(realPart);
   free(ImgPart);
            }
```

but my supervisor told me it´s wrong and I need to read more about the basics 
I´m really confused  plz help ..

Comment: There are various errors… `sizeof(ImgPart)` is just the size of a pointer, not equal to `length*sizeof(double)`, and the real and imaginary parts are both part of the *result* of a Fourier transform, so your call to `FFT` does not appear to have any input data. But what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

The bandwidth and resolution depend not only on sample rate, but on the FFT window length and shape, as well as how you measure or define bandwidth and resolution, and potentially the signal to noise ratio.